# How to configure XAMPP for a production environment

Tags: mysql, apache, codeigniter, xampp

I am trying to design my website using XAMPP but I get the below error message when I try to access the page from localhost.

[image: Error message]

I have already tried using https://localhost/media.einnovation but this time I proceed to get the below error.

[image: Error message 2]

My website uses a .htaccess file which might be blocking XAMPP from showing the website. Adding onto this my website was built using codeignitor and was recently on a cloudways server until I migrated to XAMPP.

I have read around and understand that there is most likely an issue with my configurations with XAMPP that are not supporting hosting a website in a production environment.

I have not edited the httpd.config file or the my.ini file for this.

My website has been placed inside the htdocs file and appears in the index of my localhost. Furthermore, my XAMPP apache and MySQL both work when I launch the XAMPP console.

Below is a screenshot of the folder of the files for my website.

[image: File path]

Below is the code for my .htaccess file

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteEngine On
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
#</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Lastly, below is my database.php file which I have edited to be able to import the database onto phpmyadmin.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'einnoven_media1',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Would anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: You already asked [that question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64559027). Please do not reask the same question, and edit the old one instead.

Comment: Linking the duplicate [How to set up a server using XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559027/how-to-set-up-a-server-using-xampp). On top, this looks like a configuration question, rather than programming related (see [help/on-topic]) and don't post text as image please.